# update query not work

Tags: php, mysql

This is the full code of the page which i am using to update data.I Tried many time but it still not updating values in database..also tried to echo but still not updating

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../func-tion/func.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['m_uname']) && isset($_SESSION['m_pass']))
{

?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['subup']))
{
$SQL="update appid set android_appid='".$_POST['and_a']."' , iphone_appid='".$_POST['iph_a']."' , ipad_appid='".$_POST['ipa_a']."' where u_name='".$_GET['name']."'";
echo $SQL;
}
?>



<?php 
               $main_qry=mysql_query("select * from users where u_name='".$_GET['name']."'");
              $main_fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($main_qry); 

?>
 <center><h2 class="art-postheader">Edit details of <b></b></h2></center><br/><br/>
 <table align="center">  
 <tr align="center">
  <td style="height: 60px; font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">Username:<br>
 <input type="text" name="u_name" style="width: 300px;" value="<?php echo $main_fetch['u_name']?>"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
  <td style="height: 60px; font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">Email:<br>
  <input type="text" name="u_email" style="width: 300px;" value="<?php echo $main_fetch['u_email']?>"></td>
</tr><?php 
               $main_qrys=mysql_query("select * from appid where u_name='".$_GET['name']."'");
              $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($main_qrys); 

?>      <form name="user" method="post" action="users_edit.php" onSubmit="return valid();">
 <tr align="center">
<td  style="width: 100px; font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">Android Appid:<br>
  <input type="text" name="and_a" style="width: 300px;" value="<?php echo $row['android_appid']?>"></td>

</tr>
 <tr align="center">
<td  style="width: 100px; font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">Iphone Appid:<br>
  <input type="text" name="iph_a" style="width: 300px;" value="<?php echo $row['iphone_appid']?>"></td>

</tr>
 <tr align="center">
<td  style="width: 100px; font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">Iphone(ipad) Appid:<br>
  <input type="text" name="ipa_a" style="width: 300px;" value="<?php echo $row['ipad_appid']?>"></td>

</tr>
<tr align="center">
  <td style="height: 28px;">
  <button name="subup" type="submit">Edit</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</form> 
</table>



</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>

</body></html>

<?php
 }
else
{
header("Location:notserver.php?l=fake");
}
?>
```

if anyone know..Please help me i will be very thankfull to him

Comment: Is the while loop called? What does `mysql_affected_rows()` return?

Comment: needs... sanitized... input...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Just add `or die(mysql_error())` at the end of your query, and see what happens

Comment: You could just do a single `UPDATE ... SELECT`

Comment: Why are you using a while loop when you're selecting just one row? I see this all the time, is there some crazy notion that `mysql_fetch_array()` has to be called in a loop?

Comment: You're using `$_POST` for the appid parameters, but `$_GET` for the user ID. Is that right for your application? Can you show the HTML of the form?

Comment: yes..because i am fetching id from link

Comment: now i have edited the query it still not updating database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the query:

```
UPDATE appid 
set android_appid='$android_appid', iphone_appid='$iphone_appid', ipad_appid='$ipad_appid'
where u_name IN (select u_name from users where u_id = $_GET[id])
```

I wonder why you're using `$_GET['id']` rather than `$_POST['id']` like the other parameters in your script. Make sure that's correct. And you should check for errors from `mysql_query()`; if it returns `false`, print `mysql_error()` to see the reason.

Comment: yes...because am fetching id from link...i tried your query but not works. i had edited the question  what i have used now..

Comment: Are you getting an error?  You should print `mysql_error()` when there's an error. Post the output of `echo $sqq`.

Comment: I asked you to post the output of `echo $sqq`. Maybe there's no match for the ID?

Comment: hey..i posted the output and it shows the values i have entered in fields but still not updated the values in database.

Comment: You added `echo $SQL` but haven't posted the output. And now you don't do `mysql_query($SQL);`.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. We need to see what `echo $SQL;` prints. I don't see that in your question.